Nginx mirror with $request_uri not forwarding requests at all
I have 2 servers: server-1 and server-2, and they both have nginx 1.16 installed on them.
On the server-1 nginx.conf I configured:
listen 80;
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://server-1:8080;
}

location /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://server-2:80;
}

And on the server-2 nginx.conf I configured:
listen 80;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://server-2:8080;

}

Now, When Im sending a request to server-1 Im expecting it to be forwarded with the correct path to server-2, but for some reason it sends the request but not with the correct path, but with the path /mirror.
I searched online and find this thread:
Nginx mirror not forwarding to mirror link
When they said Im "have to add the $request_uri to the proxy_pass to send the full URI to the second, mirrored backend."
So I did, now my server-1 nginx.conf is:
listen 80;
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://server-1:8080;
}

location /mirror {
    proxy_pass http://server-2:80$request_uri;
}

And now, when I check server-2 logs, Im not getting any logs...
Where am I going wrong here?

As far as I can tell, all the docs seem to be wrong on this one. I don't know why, but appending anything (e.g. $request_uri, $1, etc) to the end of the proxy_pass directive in the mirror location block seems to break the proxy forwarding.
I was finally able to get the desired behavior using rewrite like so:
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://whatever-the-primary-proxy-is.com;
  }

  location /mirror {
    internal;
    rewrite /.* $request_uri break;
    proxy_pass http://whatever-the-mirror-proxy-is.com;
  }
}

